# You have $10$ gold coins and the price today is $\$10,000$ and it appreciates $10\%$ a year. You sell $\$1000$ every month.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

- You start out with $10$ gold coins
- The price is $\$10,000$ for the entire year.
- Gold coins appreciate $10\%$ at the start of each year.
- You cash out $\$1,000$ every month.

> How many months/years will this last before you reach $0$ gold coins?

Is there a special math formula to calculate this easily? Or excel formula? What is this called?

Comment: Do you happen to know the answer beforehand, if this came from a textbook?

Comment: I can do this manually, but I was wondering if there was a special math formula that calculates this or even an excel formula.

Comment: Better to call "appreciates" in its simple form, "rises"

Comment: "Compound interest with periodic withdrawals" or "annuity" are things you could look up.  There are closed-form formulas for calculating the amount of time an annuity will last.